# Efficient method of concatenating multiple strings from multiple linked records into single strings per record chain

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table which contains records relating to absence details for an employee; when an absence is updated, instead of the existing row being updated; instead a new row is created and the LinkedRecordId field of the previous record is populated with the Id of the new record, a NULL value in the LinkedRecordId field indicates that the record is the newest in the chain.

I need to be able to retrieve a data set for all absence records with the notes of each parent record combined in one string and then list the other fields from the newest record in the chain.

Here is a cut-down version of the table containing the data:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[AbsenceData](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Notes] [varchar](max) NULL,
    [LinkedRecordId] [int] NULL,
    [CreatedAt] [datetime] NULL

)
```

My problem is **performance**; my current solution is the use of the following table-valued function which collects and concatenates the strings from all parent records in the chain:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[AbsenceNotesFor](@AbsenceDataId INT)
RETURNS @return TABLE
(
    AbsenceDataId INT 
    ,Notes VARCHAR(MAX)
)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @notes VARCHAR(MAX)
    ;WITH AbsenceNotes AS (
       SELECT
          ad.Id
          ,ad.Notes
          ,ad.CreatedAt
       FROM
          AbsenceData ad WITH (NOLOCK) 
       WHERE 
          ad.Id = @absenceDataId
       UNION ALL
       SELECT
          ad.Id
          ,ad.Notes
          ,ad.CreatedAt
       FROM
          AbsenceData ad WITH (NOLOCK) 
          INNER JOIN AbsenceNotes an ON an.Id = ad.LinkedRecordId
    )

    SELECT @notes = CONVERT(VARCHAR(11),CreatedAt, 105) + ' ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(5),CreatedAt, 114)+ CHAR(13)+CHAR(10) + CAST(Notes AS VARCHAR(MAX)) + CHAR(13)+CHAR(10) + CHAR(13)+CHAR(10) + COALESCE(@notes,'')
    FROM AbsenceNotes   

    INSERT INTO @return
       SELECT AbsenceDataId = @AbsenceDataId, Notes = @notes

    RETURN;
END
```

Here is a cut-down version of the current implementation:

```
SELECT
     Id
    ,n.Notes    
FROM AbsenceData
    CROSS APPLY dbo.AbsenceNotesFor(Id) n
WHERE 
    LinkedRecordId IS NULL
```

When running this against a dataset of a few hundred records I can already see a performance issue which seems to be due to the logic within the table valued function.

I'm looking for a more efficient way of doing this, any ideas?

We are using MS SQL Server 2016 Standard

Here is the example on SQL Fiddle:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/b9834

Comment: Table valued functions -- particularly a complicated one like this -- are going to slow down performance.  You should edit your question and provide sample data and desired results, because there might be a better way to do what you want to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Table valued functions with *multi-statement-syntax* are well known for absolutely bad performance. You should avoid if ever possible the TVF-syntax with `BEGIN` and `END`.

Much better is the same function as *inline* or *ad-hoc* function. Without sample data this is a blind flight, but I think you would get the same result, but much better performance with this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[AbsenceNotesFor](@AbsenceDataId INT)
RETURNS TABLE
AS
    RETURN
    WITH AbsenceNotes AS (
       SELECT
           ad.Id
          ,ad.Notes
          ,ad.CreatedAt
       FROM
          AbsenceData ad WITH (NOLOCK) 
       WHERE 
          ad.Id = @absenceDataId
       UNION ALL
       SELECT
          ad.Id
          ,ad.Notes
          ,ad.CreatedAt
       FROM
          AbsenceData ad WITH (NOLOCK) 
          INNER JOIN AbsenceNotes an ON an.Id = ad.LinkedRecordId
    )

    SELECT @AbsenceDataId AS AbsenceDataId
         ,(
             REPLACE
             (  
                  STUFF
                  (
                      (
                        (
                            SELECT '|#|'+ '|#|' 
                                        + CONVERT(VARCHAR(11),CreatedAt, 105) + ' ' 
                                        + CONVERT(VARCHAR(5),CreatedAt, 114)
                                        + '|#|' 
                                        + CAST(Notes AS VARCHAR(MAX))
                            FROM AbsenceNotes   
                            FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE
                        ).value('.','nvarchar(max)')
                      ),1,6,''
                  ),'|#|',CHAR(13)+CHAR(10)
            )
          ) AS Notes;
```

Short explanation:

I did not touch your CTE.

The string concatenation with `SELECT @variable=@variable + Something` is a very bad performing procedural approach. I replaced this with `FOR XML PATH('')`. You can find a lot about this if you search for `Group concat` and Sql-Server...

I replaced the line-breaks with a magic-value (`|#|`) to avoid later problems.

The `STUFF` function does nothing else than cut away the 6 characters at the beginning (two times the magic value for the line break)

The `REPLACE` function changes the magic values back to real line-breaks.

If you want the Notes in descending order (your code looks like this) just add a proper `ORDER BY` to the inner `SELECT`.

Comment: Hi Shnugo, thank you for your response and solution. It's definitely quicker this way, approximately 4 times quicker! I wonder if there is any way to completely eliminate the TVF?

Comment: Well, the *inline TVF* is - nobody had thought so! - inlined. There is not so much difference, whether you write this as TVF or - in the same place - directly into the outer (calling) statement. If performance is still an issue I'd suggest to start a new question. Provide more details about your goal and provide a [MCVE (tables, sample data, expected output)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Place a link to this new question here and I will pop up there soon (together with the helping armada of SO)

Answer (score 0):

Still having performance issues on larger sets - however after going through the execution plan in more detail; I realised that I was missing some indexes and the query was not completely 'covered', Adding the missing index which with a Key field of `Id` and an included field for `Notes` and `CreatedAt` has massively increased the performance; however I'm not sure this is wise, perhaps I need to raise another question on this subject...